# what is the reference for "Document" in this code?

Tags: c#, reference

I have this code for opening a PDF file and editing it's content but I don't know what the reference of "Document" in this code is . Here is my code :

```
//Open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document("input.pdf");
//Get particular page
Page pdfPage = (Page)pdfDocument.Pages[1];

//Create text fragment
TextFragment textFragment = new TextFragment("main text");
textFragment.Position = new Position(100, 600);

//Set text properties
textFragment.TextState.FontSize = 12;
textFragment.TextState.Font = FontRepository.FindFont("TimesNewRoman");
     textFragment.TextState.BackgroundColor=Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
    textFragment.TextState.ForegroundColor=Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

//Create TextBuilder object
TextBuilder textBuilder = new TextBuilder(pdfPage);

//Append the text fragment to the PDF page
textBuilder.AppendText(textFragment);

//Save document
pdfDocument.Save("output.pdf");
```

Comment: So how do you compile it?

Comment: Why not just hover over the declaration in Visual Studio? Then you'll see the fully qualified name.

Comment: I think it's Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word but when i choose it as a refrence then i hve error in (pdfdocuments.pages)  part.yes my document is a PDF

Comment: What do you mean by "when i choose it as a reference"? And what error do you get? It's *extremely* unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works with a library called [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/total-component.aspx) which is a commercial product. You need to buy that library or download a trial, then add the dll that you will download as reference to your project.

I'm sure the code sample was taken from a website. Look on the products from their page if you are interesting in buying. There are also free solutions for PDF. I only used ITextSharp.

Comment: ITextSharp isn't free.I want a free one.